# Не могу понять почему появляется ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, методы

```
class Class():

        def __init__(self, var):
            self.var = var
        def method(self, var1=self.var):
            print(var1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка из-за того, что вы передаете `self.var` в качестве аргумента функции. Если хотите получить доступ к переменной `var`, которую вы определили в конструкторе класса, то не нужно ее передавать в другие методы класса как отдельный аргумент - вы будете иметь к ней доступ через `self`, который является первым аргументом метода.  Попробуйте так:

```
class Class():

    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    def method(self, var2):
        return self.var + var2


obj = Class(333)


print(obj.method(111))
print(obj.var)
```

Резульат:

```
444
333
```

Comment: Позже я хочу передавать методу аргумент. Поэтому мне необходимо его указывать.

Comment: Дополнил ответ, добавив аргумент.